# STM32 HAL: How to read I2C memory in truly non-blocking mode?

Tags: c, stm32, i2c

Here's what I have: PCA9555 chip that has inputs, if a signal state on the input changes, the interrupt signal is sent. Then I can read the chip via I2C to check the inputs.

What I need - when a pin changes state, I need to read the chip, check which pin changed state and notify my app about it.

So I have an interrupt and the interrupt handler MUST NOT block the MCU.

My obvious choice is using HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_IT(), right?

I made the whole code, tested it. It seemed like it worked... For a while.

Until I added reading the chip like every 100ms.

The code still works, but I see the blinking things stutter, stop blinking for more than a second or even 2. So - it became obvious that HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_IT() BLOCKS my interrupt that causes the MCU to freeze.

I checked the HAL sources and found this:

```c
static HAL_StatusTypeDef I2C_RequestMemoryRead(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint16_t DevAddress,
                                               uint16_t MemAddress, uint16_t MemAddSize, uint32_t Timeout,
                                               uint32_t Tickstart)
{
  I2C_TransferConfig(hi2c, DevAddress, (uint8_t)MemAddSize, I2C_SOFTEND_MODE, I2C_GENERATE_START_WRITE);

  /* Wait until TXIS flag is set */
  if (I2C_WaitOnTXISFlagUntilTimeout(hi2c, Timeout, Tickstart) != HAL_OK)
  {
    return HAL_ERROR;
  }

  /* If Memory address size is 8Bit */
  if (MemAddSize == I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT)
  {
    /* Send Memory Address */
    hi2c->Instance->TXDR = I2C_MEM_ADD_LSB(MemAddress);
  }
  /* If Memory address size is 16Bit */
  else
  {
    /* Send MSB of Memory Address */
    hi2c->Instance->TXDR = I2C_MEM_ADD_MSB(MemAddress);

    /* Wait until TXIS flag is set */
    if (I2C_WaitOnTXISFlagUntilTimeout(hi2c, Timeout, Tickstart) != HAL_OK)
    {
      return HAL_ERROR;
    }

    /* Send LSB of Memory Address */
    hi2c->Instance->TXDR = I2C_MEM_ADD_LSB(MemAddress);
  }

  /* Wait until TC flag is set */
  if (I2C_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout(hi2c, I2C_FLAG_TC, RESET, Timeout, Tickstart) != HAL_OK)
  {
    return HAL_ERROR;
  }

  return HAL_OK;
}
```

As the name `I2C_WaitOnTXISFlagUntilTimeout()` suggests - it WAITS. Yes, it's a `while` loop that blocks the executing thread until a flag is set:

```c
static HAL_StatusTypeDef I2C_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint32_t Flag, FlagStatus Status,
                                                    uint32_t Timeout, uint32_t Tickstart)
{
  while (__HAL_I2C_GET_FLAG(hi2c, Flag) == Status)
  {
    /* Check for the Timeout */
    if (Timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY)
    {
      if (((HAL_GetTick() - Tickstart) > Timeout) || (Timeout == 0U))
      {
        hi2c->ErrorCode |= HAL_I2C_ERROR_TIMEOUT;
        hi2c->State = HAL_I2C_STATE_READY;
        hi2c->Mode = HAL_I2C_MODE_NONE;

        /* Process Unlocked */
        __HAL_UNLOCK(hi2c);
        return HAL_ERROR;
      }
    }
  }
  return HAL_OK;
}
```

There are 3 of those lagging functions.

For my application this is a show stopper. It just doesn't work, since it depends on handling the events in real time. Also it has a GUI that freezes when the interrupt handler blocks.

Is there a quick workaround for this? Is it a bug in HAL driver?

Do I have to implement my own non-blocking function? It seems like many, many hours of coding, since the function is non trivial and tightly coupled with the rest of the module.

My idea is to rewrite it and replace `while` loops with my non-blocking delay function that uses a timer interrupt to continue work after some time passes. To make it more non-trivial, each callback would have to receive the necessary state data to continue. Then the state machine to figure out where we are with my `I2C_RequestMemoryRead_` process. At the end I just call the registered callback and done. It should work truly non-blocking...

But I have deadlines. Can it be done faster? How is it even possible the HAL "_IT" function BLOCKS the thread with some `while` loops? It's just wrong! It defeats the entire purpose of an "interrupt mode function". If it blocks, there already IS a blocking version that is simpler.

Comment: You could always split the function into starting the transaction, checking for TXIS and checking for the flag, without any loops, of course. This way, you can start the transaction and check whether it is finished and get the result at a time convenient for you. This makes it non-blocking and is easier than waiting for timer interrupts to occur and save the state you are in during the I2C communication for the callbacks. Or do you actually need to expose a blocking function (as in "only return when done")?

Comment: @PhilMasteG: How can I check for TXIS without loops or timers? Is there a hardware generated interrupt that notifies about TXIS state changed? My call needs to exit, then continue with the state machine, then call the callback. I still need to wait for the flags somehow.

Comment: Your second code snippet has a condition of `__HAL_I2C_GET_FLAG(hi2c, Flag) == Status` for the while loop - this is what you need to check and if that condition is false you know that the event you need to wait for has occured. Or am I missing something here? -- For the TXIS flag, the condition is `__HAL_I2C_GET_FLAG(hi2c, I2C_FLAG_TXIS) == RESET`, see [here](https://os.mbed.com/users/EricLew/code/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/docs/tip/stm32l4xx__hal__i2c_8c_source.html#l03883).

Comment: @PhilMasteG I know how to test the flag, but the flag won't be set immediately. I have to WAIT for it. I need an EVENT that will trigger the testing. Original code just spins in a loop. The non-blocking code must periodically check for the flag and then read the register. There are only 2 options - 1: a timer, 2: an external notification about flags changed. How else could I know it's time to read?

Comment: By checking the flags when it is convenient to you, eg. when your processor is otherwise unoccupied. For example, if you have a bigger statemachine, check the flags in every iteration of that state machine and by checking the flags you know that the result is ready and you can read the result. You can integrate this into your bigger code loop so that this originally implemented tight checking loop does not block the rest of your code.

Comment: The best way is to use RTOS

Comment: @PhilMasteG Oh, now I understand. I used timer interrupt anyway. It works, however I haven't found a good way to extend the default HAL driver other than replacing original C file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with hacking the original HAL driver.

https://gist.github.com/HTD/e36fb68488742f27a737a5d096170623

After adding the files to the project the original HAL driver needs to be modified as described in the stm32h7xx_hal_i2c_nb.h comment.

For use with STM32CubeIDE it's best to move the modified driver file to a different location to prevent the IDE from overwriting it.

I left other *IT functions unchanged, but it's very easy to add similar modifications to all remaining functions.

The hacked driver was tested in real world application on my STM32H747I-DISCO board with PCA9555 16-bit I/O expander.

For the test I spammed the input with random noise signals that just crashed the original driver. Here it works, doesn't block other threads, the GUI works with full speed.